# Facebook max width

Tags: facebook, width, max

I am developing an app for Facebook and I'm totally confused over what is the max width you can use. I thought it was 520px which fits between the page links and profile picture to the left and the adverts and stuff to the right.

But I keep seeing people saying you can use up to 760px. Is this true? I've never seen an example of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for page tab, it is 520px
for canvas app, if you are using fixed width, then it is 760
    and if you are using fluid canvas width, then it is limited by the width of the browser

Comment: I still don't quite follow? So if you use a fixed width of 760 would the iframe get rid of the adverts and stuff to the right. Sorry to be so dim.

Comment: Ok. I'm still not following this. And I may well be implementing something wrong.  I've created a company page on Facebook and I want to create an app that is around 750px wide. Desn't matter what I set the canvas width to, either fluid or fixed 760, it still only occupies the middle of the screen. EG. [link](http://www.facebook.com/pages/Astle-Group/246816458703073?sk=app_288140734544235)     What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you cannot get rid of the other sections / page elements that facebook placed on the page.

Comment: So the final answer is: For a company page app the max width is 520px?